# The model backing the 'AccountingDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First

Tags: entity-framework-6

I know there are many topics about this error message but none of them is similar my problem. I am using Entity Framework 6. I have changed my entity and I have to run add-migration and then update-database. but when I run add-migration the newly created class `public partial class Test: DbMigration` contains two empty Up and Down methods. so when I run update-database it does not make any changes on the database. and I am get this error always.

I am getting this error when I run update-database. I think the problem occur becasue UP and Down methods are empty and no changes are made into the database when I run update-database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that want to know what was the problem. 
When you create a MVC 5 project with Idenity, it adds ApplicationDbContext class to connect to the database. I had created another DBContext for my entities. When I changed my entities and run add-migration it affected only chnages that was made for those ootb entities which belong to ApplicationDbContext not my DBContext. and When I run update-database it does not update my entities. I added all my entities to ApplicationDbContext and run add-migration then update-database and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in  `Application_Start()` Method in `Global.asax.cs` file write as first line this

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDBContext>(null);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but this doesn't solve my problem. You ususaly use this if you know that you haven't changed your entity and you still get this error. But I have changed the entity and I have to run update-database and I am getting this error when I run update-database